# Data exchange from Nodejs to Python is not working properly

Tags: python, node.js

I have created a webhook for Dialogflow using Nodejs.

Now I need to call a Python file to summarize the text. I use **python-shell** for this action. As an argument, I add text that I want to shorten.

The problem is that the text about defenestration, for example, is sent correctly except for "**v roce**". Python will receive it as "**v**\xa0**roce**". The rest of the text is fine. Other text may have more than one this problem.

I tried to call Python with the same text as argument from the command line and this problem did not occur.

Code sample in Nodejs

```
            var options = {
              mode: 'text',
              args: result
            };

            await PythonShell.run('summary.py', options, function (err, results) {
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(result);
              }
              // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
              else{
                result = results.toString();
                let output = {
                  fulfillmentText: result,
                  outputContexts: []
                };
                result = JSON.stringify(output);
                callback(result);
            }
            });
```

If I call `print (sys.argv [1])` at the beginning of the Python code, I get this

> Původ slova je odvozován od pražské defenestrace **v roce** 1618, kdy
>   nespokojení protestanští stavové vyhodili z okna dva královské
>   místodržící a k tomuto činu sepsali obsáhlou apologii.

This looks good, but after doing this

```
article = filedata.split(". ")
sentences = []

for sentence in article:
    sentences.append(sentence.replace("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").split(" "))
sentences.pop()

print(sentences)

return sentences
```

The following will return

> "[['Defenestrace', 'označuje', 'násilné', 'vyhození', 'z', 'okna'],
>   ['Původ', 'slova', 'je', 'odvozován', 'od', 'pražské', 'defenestrace',
>   '**v\xa0roce**', '1618,', 'kdy', 'nespokojení', 'protestanští',
>   'stavové', 'vyhodili', 'z', 'okna', 'dva', 'královské', 'místodržící',
>   'a', 'k', 'tomuto', 'činu', 'sepsali', 'obsáhlou', 'apologii'],
>   ['Ovšem', 've', 'středověku', 'a', 'v', 'raném', 'novověku', 'se',
>   'defenestrace', 'konaly', 'poměrně', 'často', 'a', 'toto', 'konání',
>   'neslo', 'prvky', 'lynče,', 'ordálu', 'a', 'společně', 'spáchané',
>   'vraždy'], ['Ve', 'středověké', 'a', 'raně', 'novověké',
>   'společnosti,', 'která', 'je', 'výrazně', 'horizontálně', 'členěna,',
>   'má', 'defenestrace', 'charakter', 'symbolického', 'trestu']]"

I call this Python code using `generate_summary(sys.argv[1], 2)`.

If I enter "*TEXT ABOUT DEFENESTRATION*" instead of `sys.argv[1]`, this problem does not occur and is displayed "**v roce**".

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not supported in replace, you need to use [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module instead like this:

```
 re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", your_string)
```

And then split the result into words.

Comment: It looks like **v roce** already works, but everything else will be destroyed

[['Defenestrace', 'ozna', 'uje', 'n', 'siln', '', 'vyhozen', '', 'z', 'okna'], ['P', 'vod', 'slova', 'je', 'odvozov', 'n', 'od', 'pra', 'sk', '', 'defenestrace', 'v', 'roce', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'kdy', 'nespokojen', '', 'protestan', 't', '', 'stavov', '', 'vyhodili'.....

`sentences.append(re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", sentence).split(" "))`

Comment: @KarelKrýda what result do you expect? This isn't obvious from your question.

Comment: Diacritics of type č,ě,š,á,é are replaced by a space. I need the code to accept diacritics.
For example, "Daněk pláče" should be ['Daněk ', 'pláče'], but now it's ['Dan', 'k ', 'pl','e']

Comment: \xa0 is not printable no-break space - https://www.codetable.net/hex/a0 This will not gona work with print, I guess, because "\xa0".isprintable() will return False

Comment: also, running 
s = "Původ slova je odvozován od pražské defenestrace v\xa0roce 1618 kdy nespokojení Daněk pláče"
lst = re.sub(pattern, " ", s)
result = list(word for word in lst.split(' ') if word)
print(result)
will give this result: ['Původ', 'slova', 'je', 'odvozován', 'od', 'pražské', 'defenestrace', 'v\xa0roce', 'kdy', 'nespokojení', 'Daněk', 'pláče']

Comment: I had to create this long pattern for accepting Czech diacritics

`sentences.append(re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9ÁáČčĎďÉéĚěÍíŇňÓóŘřŠšŤťÚúŮůÝýŽž,]", " ", sentence).split(" "))`

Comment: For example, if I have 2014-2017, - is taken as space...Instead of 2014-2017 I receive 2014 2017

Comment: @KarelKrýda just extend a bit the patter: sentenses = list(word for word in re.sub("[^\xa0a-zA-Z0-9-á-žÁ-Ž]", " ", s).split(" ") if word) This will give you: ['Původ', 'slova', 'je', 'odvozován', 'od', 'pražské', 'defenestrace', 'v roce', 'kdy', 'nespokojení', 'Daněk', 'pláče', '2014-2015']

Comment: Unfortunately, this code left "**\\xa0**", which was the original intention to remove. I tried to search and found a simple and functional solution.

`filedata = filedata.replace('\xa0', ' ')`

Then I used **for** with `sentences.append(sentence.replace("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").split(" "))`

This eliminated the problem and allowed me to have **2014-2017** as well as diacritics

Comment: But I have encountered another problem. Is it possible to split only if the dot is followed by a space and a capital letter? On the date "8. March", the dot is taken as the end of the sentence.